# Django database introspection

Tags: database, django, database-schema, django-south

I'd like to introspect the Django database(or table) at the runtime. So, for example- I'd like to do something like:

```
>>> a = django.db.introspect()
and now *a* should see like
a = {
    'table_name1':{
        'column_name_1_1':{
            'index': True,
            'unique': True,
            'pk': True
        },
        'column_name_1_2':{
            'index': True,
            'unique': False,
            'pk': False
        }
    },
    'table_name2':{
        'column_name_2_1':{
            'index': True,
            'unique': True,
            'pk': True
        },
        'column_name_2_2':{
            'index': True,
            'unique': False,
            'pk': False
        }
    }
}
```

And- I'd like to do that with Django & South and without any 3rd party tools(I know that I coul do that with SQLAlchemy). I want to introspect the actual db, not the frozen one in my last migration. Is that possible? How can I start?

Comment: Since your Django models provides all of this information, why do you want to mess with "introspection"?  You already have this in your `models.py` modules.  Or do you want Django to build models for you from an existing database?

Comment: Let's say, that I don't really trust that my models are consistent with DB(after several bad South migrations and several good ones)- I've got a big mess in my project and I'd like to fix this.

Comment: But that doesn't sound like something you'd want to do at runtime. You want to do this once, and then fix it.

Comment: Maybe runtime is bad word- so it's my mistake. But I'd like to do that in several projects and I'd like to make more generic solution to fixing not consistent databases.

Comment: "I'd like to make more generic solution to fixing not consistent databases".  Please describe the actual problem you actually have.  It's hard to understand fixing not-consistent databases with the database models created by Django and some kind of "introspection" or "reverse engineering" or whatever it is you're talking about.  Can you clarify what your **actual** problem is?

Comment: My **actual** problem was- _How to get database structure using Python & Django [& South]_. Why do I need that- it doesn't matters. And I've found the answer in the Django inspectdb command code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found my answer- here is everything I need:

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py